# 3 dimensional array index out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, multidimensional-array

This is my first question here. I am trying to write a program that reads as many arrays as I input from the keyboard. After inputting the number of columns I get the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Thanks in advance.

```
package Final;

import java.util.*;

public class Final {
    int a,b,x,l;
    double mat[][][];

    Final()
    {
        a=0;
        b=0;
        c=0;
        d=0;
        x=0;
        l=0;
    }

    public void read() {
        Scanner citast = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many arrays do you want to enter?");
        x=citast.nextInt();
        for (this.l=0; this.l<x; this.l++)
        {
              System.out.println("Matrix "+this.l);
              System.out.println("Number of lines: ");
              this.a = citast.nextInt();
              System.out.println("Number of columns: ");
              this.b = citast.nextInt();
              this.mat= new double [this.l][a][b];
              for (int i=0; i<this.a; i++)
               {
                  for (int j=0; j<this.b; j++)
                   {
                      System.out.print("Matrice " + l + " ["+ i +"]["+ j +"]= ");
                      this.mat[l][i][j]=citast.nextInt();
                   }
                  System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Final a = new Final();
        Scanner citast = new Scanner(System.in);
        a.read();
        System.out.println();

}

}
```

Comment: What is the point of having `Scanner citast = new Scanner(System.in);` in main?

Comment: try to give meaningful variables names like rows height columnsIterator...

Comment: Do you really want to allow differently sized matrices for each l?

Comment: @inixsoftware The code was edited here, I have more functions in the program and I forgot to remove the Scanner.

Comment: The irony of having a mutable class named Final

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.mat= new double [this.l][a][b];
```

Should be:

```
this.mat= new double [x][a][b];
```

But your code is wrong, you should set the dimension of the array before the first for loop :

```
public void read() {
        Scanner citast = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many arrays do you want to enter?");
        x=citast.nextInt();
        this.mat = new double[x][][]; //<-- added this line
        for (this.l=0; this.l<x; this.l++)
        {
            System.out.println("Matrix "+this.l);
            System.out.println("Number of lines: ");
            this.a = citast.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Number of columns: ");
            this.b = citast.nextInt();
            this.mat[l] =  new double [a][b]; //<-- modified this line
            for (int i=0; i<this.a; i++)
                for (int j=0; j<this.b; j++)
                {
                    System.out.print("Matrice " + l + " ["+ i +"]["+ j +"]= ");
                    this.mat[l][i][j]=citast.nextInt();
                }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(mat));
    }
```

Output for an array containing 2 square matrices (one filled with 4 and one with 5):

```
[[[4.0, 4.0], [4.0, 4.0]], [[5.0, 5.0], [5.0, 5.0]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.
At first you create an array of size `x` to hold arbitrary sized two-dimensional arrays.
Then for each `l` you create a two-dimensional array of size `a` x `b`, put it at position `l` of `mat` and read the values into it.

```
Scanner citast = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How many arrays do you want to enter?");
x=citast.nextInt();

this.mat = new double[x][][];

for (this.l=0; this.l<x; this.l++) {
    System.out.println("Matrix "+this.l);
    System.out.println("Number of lines: ");
    this.a = citast.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Number of columns: ");
    this.b = citast.nextInt();
    this.mat[this.l] = new double [a][b];
    for (int i=0; i<this.a; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<this.b; j++)
        {
            System.out.print("Matrice " + l + " ["+ i +"]["+ j +"]= ");
            this.mat[l][i][j]=citast.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int j=0; j<this.b; j++)
    {
        System.out.print("Matrice " + l + " ["+ i +"]["+ j +"]= ");
        this.mat[l][i][j]=citast.nextInt();
    }
```

If you leave

```
this.mat[l][i][j] = citast.nextInt();
```

out of it, then it's working.

Also you have to make Final() static and declare c and d in your class, because they are in the constructor, but there is no reference to them in the class.